# bulldozer iOS SDK error

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I keep getting

> No iPhone SDK found

error when trying to deploy my app on my old iPhone 5. I tried installing java jdk and jre but it still does not work. If anyone has a solution please help. thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1028, in run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 90, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 100, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 171, in prepare_for_build
self.target.check_requirements()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/ios.py", line 82, in check_requirements
'No iPhone SDK found. Please install at least one iOS SDK.')
```

Exception: No iPhone SDK found. Please install at least one iOS SDK.
emmanuels-MacBook-Air:breaktime emmanuelnabi$

Comment: Have you installed the [IOS SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_SDK) (formerly iPhone SDK)?

Comment: Developer Tools:

  Version: 8.2 (8C30a)
  Location: /Users/emmanuelnabi/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app
  Applications:
  Xcode: 8.2 (11764)
  Instruments: 8.2 (61755)
  SDKs:
  iOS:
  10.2: (14C5077a)
  iOS Simulator:
  10.2: (14C5077a)
  macOS:
  10.12: (16C48a)
  tvOS:
  10.1: (14U5582a)
  tvOS Simulator:
  10.1: (14U5582a)
  watchOS:
  3.1: (14S471a)
  watchOS Simulator:
  3.1: (14S471a)             this what i see under developer so i think iPhone SDK is installed